# Using typedefs to simplify declarations: int *(*x[10])(void);

Tags: c

Could someone explain what is going on when we use the typedef "type
cast" syntax?

```
    typedef int (*funcptr)(double); (Wiki)
    funcptr x = (funcptr) NULL;
```

OR

pg470, K.N.King - Modern Approach

```
    typedef int *Fcn(void);
    typedef Fcn *Fcn_ptr;
    typedef Fcn_ptr Fcn_ptr_array[10];
    Fcn_ptr_array x;
```

Isn't it:

```
    typedef oldtype newtype;
    typedef int Bool;
```

So how does: typedef int * Fcn(void) make sense?? 
Usually: int *Fcn(void), would be a function "Fcn" that has no
parameters and returns a pointer to an int.. if i stick a typedef what
happens??

funcptr is a pointer variable.. it's not a type..? so how can he cast
NULL to (funcptr)???? Is this syntax explained clearly somewhere -
K.N.King just slams it into you without mentioning this peculiar syntax
anywhere..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from 《C language reference manual》, chapter 7:

> Declarations with the storage class specifier typedef do not define storage. A typedef has the following syntax: typedef-name: identifier.An identifier appearing in a typedef declaration becomes a synonym for the type rather than becoming an object with the given type.

so typedef int (*funcptr)(double) means funcptr is a function pointer,the function has one parameter double and return type is int.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for defining a `typedef` in C is *identical* to the definition of a variable, but with the keyword `typedef` prepended.

So, if for example:

```
int a[10];
```

declares `a` as a variable of type array-of-10-ints, then the following:

```
typedef int b[10];
```

defines `b` as the type array-of-10-ints.

The same is true for function types:

```
int f(double);
```

declares `f` as a function that receives a `double` and returns an `int`. Then:

```
typedef int g(double);
```

defines `g` as the type of such a function.

Naturally, you cannot declare a variable of type *function*, so the following is incorrect:

```
g ag; //Error
```

But you can use it to declare variables of type pointer-to-function:

```
g *pg; //OK
```

That's why it is usually preferred to make the typedef a pointer-to-function in the first place:

```
typedef int (*k)(double);
```

Here `k` is a pointer-to-function that receives a double and returns an int.
This way you can declare a variable `pg` equivalent to the avobe with:

```
k pg;
```

Comment: Actually, `g ag;` is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef int (*funcptr)(double);` is defining `funcptr` as a **function pointer**, where the function being pointed to takes a single argument of type `double`, and returns an `int`.

Otherwise `x` will have to be declared as: `int (*x)(double)`. It saves you from having to type this all out every time you want a variable of this type somewhere. Not to mention it makes making changes to your code easier.

You can assign `NULL` to *any* sort of pointer to say that your pointer isn't pointing anywhere valid (`funcptr x = (funcptr) NULL;`). `NULL` will be defined as a `void*` to an invalid memory location, you don't need to cast it to assign it to `x`.

Your second example merely breaks the `typedef` up into a couple more steps, with the result being a `typedef` for an array of function pointers.